# How can I convert SQL output to a CSV file?

Tags: peoplesoft, sqr, peoplecode

I want to create a SQL output to CSV-type file.

I am using Peoplesoft's IDE, PeopleTools Application Designer. I have an [Application Engine process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAi7m.jpg) that can loop and do set-based processing.

Is there a PeopleCode sample I can use?

Answer (score 1):

PeopleCode works very well with [Rowsets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F28299_01/pt857pbr3/eng/pt/tpcr/concept_UnderstandingRowsetClass-c07c5a.html?pli=ul_d38e1282_tpcr), so if you can create a View Record and put the SQL in there, then you can invoke the Record in PeopleCode and feed it into a File Layout definition.

I think this is the PeopleSoft way to do it.

Here's an example from PeopleBooks documentation:

- PeopleBooks > PeopleSoft PeopleTools 8.57 > Products > Development Tools > PeopleCode API Reference > File Class > [File Layout Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F28299_01/pt857pbr3/eng/pt/tpcr/task_FileLayoutExamples-071429.html)

Here are a few links that came up when I searched the web for: [peoplesoft file layout rowset](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=peoplesoft+file+layout+rowset):

- https://psoftadmirer.blogspot.com/2015/07/exporting-record-data-using-file-layout.html
- http://www.psoftsearch.com/peoplesoft-standalone-rowset/